# Dynamics CRM 2011 Sharepoint Reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

i have a Problem with CRM and JavaScript. I would like to reference the sharepoint library in a JavaScript file. But it doesn´t work... How can i reference the sharepoint library?

For example:

```
/// <reference path="C:\sp.js" /> 

function testFieldChange() {

    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
    ODataPath = serverUrl + "/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";

    // ... sharepoint code ...

    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('test_field').setValue('Test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to upload your sp.js file as a CRM web resource. Once you've done that it can be referenced as a script library in your forms and other JS code.

You can read more about using JScript in CRM [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309414.aspx)